# TabBar disappearing after segue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue, tabbar

I'm trying to perform a manual segue from a VC to a different VC which is in a TabViewController.
When I do that the tab bar it self disappears for some reason. I've tried to imbed all the TabVCs in NavigationControllers but it didn't help.
Here is the scheme of the project: [image: project storyboard scheme]

As you can see, there is an initial navigation controller and then I try to connect the user to a tab view controller after he logs in.
The segue code:

`self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "AfterLogin", sender: self)`
The segue works("show") but the tab bar disappears.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the details of your segue?

Comment: You say *"The segue works("show")"* ... Do you mean, from the VC at top-left in your image, you are doing a "show" segue to the TabBar controller in the center? If so, does that TabBar controller get "pushed"? That is, does it "slide in from right" as a standard NavigationController push animation? Or does it "slide up from the bottom"? And, you say *"but the tab bar disappears"* ... does that mean you ***see** the tab bar, and then it "goes away"? Or do you never see the tab bar?

Answer (score -1):

thank you everyone!
I found a solution that is quit helpful.
For some reason I've created a "loading screen" and made a segue between the login screen to it. with dispatqueue I've made a 1 sec delay then made a segue between the loading screen to the final wanted screen. That created a sort of loading filling while fixing the problem.

Comment: this sounds like a fundamental bad way to incorporate this functionality. I would highly suggest rethinking your solution.